# standard draw is key pressed skips stages

Tags: java

In standard draw there is a `isKeyPressed()` function. The function returns a `boolean` indicating if the parameter was pressed.

In a text based game I am making, the user will press `y` or `n`to determine an outcome. Sometimes, but not always, the following story text is skipped. here is my code. I am running this in eclipse. This is not all of my code, but where I believe the problem is.

```
while(true){

else if(stage == 6){

StdDraw.textLeft(0, 700,"'so, ya name's "+ name + ", huh?'");

StdDraw.textLeft(0, 680,"'What an odd name if i do say so.'");

StdDraw.textLeft(0, 660,"'you're lucky i found you when i did, the dark forest is dangerous!'");

StdDraw.textLeft(0, 620,"'So, you heading to Ivangard, right?'(y/n)");
            counter = 1;

if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed('Y')&&frame%8==0){

stage = 7;

            }
else if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed('N')&&frame%8==0){
                    stage = 9;
            }
        }
else if(stage == 7){

StdDraw.textLeft(0, 700,"'well lucky you! i'm going in the same direction!'");

    StdDraw.textLeft(0, 680,"'Well i'm Program "+ random +", nice to meet you.'");

    StdDraw.textLeft(0, 660,"'take this rusty dagger. may be of use!'");

    StdDraw.textLeft(0, 640,"'ill see you in Ivangaurd!'");

                    StdDraw.textLeft(0, 500,"continue?(O)");

                    if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed('O')&&frame%12==0){

                        stage = 11;

                        programn = random;

                        fist = 0;

                        rustyd = 1;

                }

                }



            else if(stage == 9){

        StdDraw.textLeft(0, 700,"'Well, if you need me, ill be in Ivangaurd'");

        StdDraw.textLeft(0, 680,"'I'm Program #"+ random +", nice to meet you.'");

        StdDraw.textLeft(0, 660,"'take this rusty dagger. may be of use!'");

                StdDraw.textLeft(0, 620,"continue?(O)");

                counter = 1;

                programn = random;

                fist = 0;

                rustyd = 1;



                if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed('O')&&frame%12==0){

                    stage = 11;

            }

            }

else if(stage == 11){

        StdDraw.textLeft(0, 700,"Part 2: The virus");

    StdDraw.textLeft(0, 660,"as you leave the dark forest, The voice comes back");

    StdDraw.textLeft(0, 640,"A great evil is coming to this land.");

        StdDraw.textLeft(0, 620,"a virus, a plague the program...");

        StdDraw.textLeft(0, 600,"unlike the program, all the virus does is eat.");

                StdDraw.textLeft(0, 580,"That is why we need you.");

StdDraw.textLeft(0, 560,"you are human, uneatable to the virus. All other warriors would fall were you stand.");

                StdDraw.textLeft(0, 540,"continue?(0)");

                if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed('O')&&frame%12==0){

                    stage = 10;

                }

            }

}
```

The problem is after the y/n option, it skips the following text.

the new text is here. I am novice coder, so i may not have understood what you told me to do.

```
else if(stage == 6){
            StdDraw.textLeft(0, 700,"'so, ya name's "+ name + ", huh?'");
            StdDraw.textLeft(0, 680,"'What an odd name if i do say so.'");
            StdDraw.textLeft(0, 660,"'you're lucky i found you when i did, the dark forest is dangerous!'");
            StdDraw.textLeft(0, 620,"'So, you heading to Ivangard, right?'(y/n)");
            counter = 1;
            if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed('Y')&&frame%8==0){
                stage = 7;

            }
            if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed('N')&&frame%8==0){
                stage = 9;
            }
        }
```

Comment: the problem is after the y/n option, it skips the following text.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or warnings from the compiler?

Answer (score 2):

`StdDraw.isKeyPressed()` takes in an `int` not a `char`

```
public static boolean isKeyPressed(int keycode)
```

> returns true if keycode is currently being pressed, false otherwise

[StdDraw.isKeyPressed](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdDraw.html#isKeyPressed%28int%29)

See [KeyEvent.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) for a description of keycodes.

**Update:** The OP asked for an example:

```
if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_Y) {
   // True if the 'y' key is currently being pressed
}
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer: ah yes, updating now

Comment: @DougRamsey +1 for the spotting the problem!

Comment: changed it to KeyEvent.VK_Y . no error, but still skips the text

Comment: Hm, perhaps the method was overloaded and not documented in the published Java Docs

Comment: My comment basically said there is still an error somewhere. What I meant by overloading was that the method can take in either a `character` or an `int`, but wasn't documented that way. This would justify if the compiler was not giving warnings or errors.

Comment: @user1507910: Just a thought, there is another condition in your code: `&&frame%8==0`. We can't see how `frame` is being set, try removing this to see if you get your text. That could be the source of the error.

Comment: at the end of my while(true) loop; frame is frame++; and is set to 0 at the start of my code. i removed it, and it just skipped over the text slower, i.e. i press y and i see it for a split second, the the next group of text for the same amount of time, and so on.

Comment: @user1507910: You see the text for a split second? That means its being reset. Print to the console to make sure.

Comment: the big question for me is sometimes it works and other times it doesn't.

Comment: print what to the console? the frame? it constantly goes up.

Comment: @user1507910: Another thought: You are in an infinite `while` loop. Are there any `break` or `return` statements that you have not included on your post?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you tried to change the execution path of an else-if statement.  You can't do this.

```
if (animal == sheep) {

   System.out.println("Fox in a sheep skin");
   animal = fox;

} else if (animal == fox) {

   System.out.println("hide the sheep");

}
```

Now basically, if `animal == sheep` then the first statement is executed ELSE if `animal == fox` then the second statement is executed.  You can't change the flow in side, cause it's already decided on a path of execution.

It's like coming to fork in a road, you can only go in one direction, not both...

```
if (animal == sheep) {

   System.out.println("Fox in a sheep skin");
   animal = fox;

} 

if (animal == fox) {

   System.out.println("hide the sheep");

}
```

Will do what you want, it's more expensive because it condition needs to be checked, but it forces the execution flow through each statement.

**UPDATE**

I suspect you misunderstood where to make the changes (without any proof to say otherwise, it's difficult to know)

This is what it should look like (I took out the text statements to make it easier to read)

```
if(stage == 6){

    //... some text

    if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed('Y')&&frame%8==0){
        stage = 7;
    } else if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed('N')&&frame%8==0){
        stage = 9;
    }
}

if(stage == 7){

    //... some text

    if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed('O')&&frame%12==0){

        stage = 11;

        programn = random;

        fist = 0;

        rustyd = 1;

    }

}

if(stage == 9) {

    //... some text

    if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed('O')&&frame%12==0){

        stage = 11;

    }

}

if(stage == 11){

    //... some text

    if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed('O')&&frame%12==0){

        stage = 10;

    }

}
```

Comment: Would you be kind enough to update your example with your new code so I might have some kind of idea of what you've done, please

Comment: changed to if statements. why doesn't it work? i increased the frame delay, and the next bit of text waits the frame delay, then goes on to the next bit of text without imputing 'O'.

Comment: @user1507910 Check my update and see if it matches what you've done

Comment: i wanted to inform you that all of this is in a wile(true) loop.